# What are the functions of the diodes in this BLDC controller circuit?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, diodes, brushless-dc-motor, automotive

I'm trying to understand the function of the diodes in this snippet of an automotive BLDC controller.  I believe that D102 is for over-voltage protection, and reverse polarity protection.  Also, I think D104 is for reverse polarity protection.  I can't figure out what D103 is for.  Any ideas?

- ETAT_MJP - this is an open collector output PWM diagnostic to the vehicle ECU.
- ETAT_MJP_PIC - from the PIC for the diagnostic output.
- PIC_ETAT_Monitor - monitoring the output diagnostic (input to PIC).
- CDE_MJP - PWM command from vehicle ECU.
- CDE_MJP_PIC - PWM command going to PIC input.

[image]

Comment: when ETAT_MJP_PIC is high, it holds the base of T102 at ~ 1.2V, therefore the emmiter of T102 at ~ 0.6V ..... when T102 is on, T102 & R107 will then sink ~ 100mA ......... the 100mA may have something to do with some communication protocol

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Why jsotola did not post that comment as an answer, I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

To mimic what @jsotola already commented, D103 clamps the base of T102 at 1.25 VDC, so the emitter is fixed at 600 mV. This sinks a fixed 100 mA to ground for bias purposes.

This only happens when ETAT_MJP_PIC is high, else this bias is OFF, allowing ETAT_MJP to rise to its maximum voltage.

The voltage source for ETAT_MJP is not shown. The lack of voltages suggest this is part of a comm link.

Comment: In the vehicle application, the open collector ETAT_MJP output would most likely get pulled high (near the ECU input) to battery level (13.5V) with an external 1k-10k resistor.  So, D103 is there just in case someone puts too low of a pull-up resistor in, or puts 13.5V on ETAT_MJP directly.  By clamping the base, the emitter current is limited and thus protects the transistor from an over current condition.  Does this sound right?

Comment: Although, I just looked up the spec sheet on T102.  The collector current is rated for 500mA.  I don't see how it could ever get near that level even if battery was connected directly to the collector.

Comment: I understand that the diode is there to clamp the base voltage, but why?  Check out the second circuit in this link.  Perhaps the diode is for temperature compensation?  http://www.brainkart.com/article/Diode-and-Thermistor-Compensation-technique_13235/

Comment: The diodes forward Vdrop will lower with increasing temperature, so T102 would lower its current, but only by a small amount. Other than being a diagnostic port, there is little info to work with. It is a small part of a much larger system.